# I am trying to implement react-inner-image-zoom with react-image-LightBox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-image-lightbox

I am using react-image-LightBox and in that, I have to implement the Zoom-in/Zoom-out feature as (https://laurenashpole.github.io/react-inner-image-zoom/).

I tried integrating react-inner-image-zoom with react-image-LightBox, but I was unable to find the solution (Desired Solution :- Using react-image-lightbox we need to use the functionality same as- https://laurenashpole.github.io/react-inner-image-zoom/ )

So, if anyone can provide the solution that will be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.